# Nokia Lumia 620 different battery consumption rates in idle screen

Tags: battery

I have a pretty new Nokia Lumia 620 (15 days of life).

I'm very careful with it, especially regarding battery care. I have read a lot of papers about proper battery usage now and two years ago when I bought my new laptop, so now I know almost everything on how to use and recharge Li-ion batteries in the proper way.

I'm also care with regarding battery consumption. Sometimes, when I know that I'm not expecting to use my smartphone in the next few hours, I check its battery consumption rate when it's completely idle (smartphone on but with lock screen).

All the apps in background are disabled, except Whatsapp.

My curiosity arises by the observation of the battery percentage before locking the screen and after 3 hours immediately after resume with the smartphone never used.

Sometimes before the lock screen and after the smartphone resume the battery level showed is the same or 1% lower (after 3 hours), other times it is 6-7% lower (always after 3 hours).

Why a so high difference?

I must mention that the smartphone is placed always in the same place, so there are no difference of network coverage or so on.

It is only a curiosity on what can be the reasons.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Assuming you're signed into Twitter and Facebook, more activity (by friends, etc) can mean more data is downloaded which may account for the extra battery usage. To verify, you'd have to turn on Battery Saver mode and monitor battery usage again.

Comment: I've never thought about it (I mean to turn on Battery Saver mode). However, I was not signed nor into Twitter nor Facebook. The only app that was running was Whatsapp, but I received no message in the meanwhile. I will try Battery Saver mode to see if these differences already exist. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You should decreas your brightness
And you have to use internet for a low time. You should clear chache and ram on time.and off all the lights of phone.